# Custom highlights in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a new bie to elastic search. I have a task where I have to highlight certain queries with specific tags.

I am using a similar query mentioned in elastic search intervals. The problem now is I have to highlight "my favourite food" with a html tag,say "favorite" and cold porridge / hot water with a different html tag, say "state".

How I can do that.

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "intervals" : {
      "my_text" : {
        "all_of" : {
          "ordered" : true,
          "intervals" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "query" : "my favourite food",
                "max_gaps" : 0,
                "ordered" : true
              }
            },
            {
              "any_of" : {
                "intervals" : [
                  { "match" : { "query" : "hot water" } },
                  { "match" : { "query" : "cold porridge" } }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "boost" : 2.0,
        "_name" : "favourite_food"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) feature in Elasticsearch as follows:

```
GET /index_name/_search
{
  "query": {},
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "type": "unified",
        "number_of_fragments": 0,
        "pre_tags": [
          "<first_filter>",
          "<second_filter>",
          "<third filter>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "<first_filter>",
          "<second_filter>",
          "<third filter>"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The order in which the tags are applied depends on the order in which the filters applied. Also note that, applying `number_of_fragments:0` returns the entire content with the tagged hits.